# Retrieving Vectors from existing Pinecone Vector Database

Tags: langchain, py-langchain, vector-database, pinecone, retrieval-augmented-generation

I have created a vector database on pinecone and am unable to retrieve vectors from it.

For my RAG application, I have successfully created a Vector Database on Pinecone, and now am trying to retrieve vectors from it.
This is my code for the same:

```
searcher = PineconeVectorStore(index_name, embeddings)

retriever = searcher.as_retriever()
retriever.search_kwargs['top_k'] = 25
retriever.search_kwargs['maximal_marginal_relevance'] = True
retriever.search_kwargs['k'] = 15

chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
    llm=llm, 
    retriever=retriever,
    verbose=True
)

handler = StdOutCallbackHandler()

print(chain.run(
    'Sample Question',
    callbacks=[handler]
))
```

I am getting the following error:

> PineconeVectorStore.similarity_search_with_score() got an unexpected keyword argument 'top_k'

I don't understand why I am getting this error as if I stored the vectors in my RAM, the same code works.

Please let me know how I should proceed.

Comment: Comment out this line `retriever.search_kwargs['top_k'] = 25`